# Set qualification requirements for MTURK external HIT using Boto

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I have these lines in my python code. I am using the boto library to connect to amazon Mturk

```
import boto

userqualification = boto.mturk.qualification.NumberHitsApprovedRequirement(comparator='GreaterThan', integer_value=50)
```

But I get this error when the code run the code

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'qualification'

I'm not sure why this is happening. I have the boto folders in the same directory as my code file.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the file `boto/mturk/qualification.py` exist in your project folder? I saw it in their source code and I can't think of a good reason why would `boto.mturk.qualification` not exist if the file exists. I know it is possible to remove it at run time, but who would to such a thing? And why? Also, which version of boto are you using? Please [edit] your question to include the output of `import boto; print(boto.Version)`.

Comment: I am also surprised, because the file exists. What I have done now, is to add an explicit import boto.mturk.qualification and it now works. Could you write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry. I'm stupid. I totally forgot how python package imports work. The behavior you encountered is "correct". If `foo` is a package, `foo.bar` is a module and `foo.__init__` doesn't import `foo.bar` then `import foo` will not import `foo.bar`, but `foo.bar` might still be accessible if some other code that executed before that point contains a statement `import foo.bar`.

Comment: Update: while writing the answer I managed to find a duplicate. I'm flagging this question to be closed. Sorry.